# Connection failed: Connection timed out

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a login system for my website but every time I try connect it says failed.

```php
<?php
$servername = "remotemysql.com";
$username = "no";
$password = "no";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

It's supposed to connect but it just says Connection failed: Connection timed out

Comment: Can we assume that you have replaced the actual `$servername`, `$username` and `$password` values with dummies here? Otherwise, if you copied this from somewhere that would be your issue.

Comment: your hoster should have a description which parameter port username passwort  etc you have to use

Comment: the password and users name are correct in the actual code @daShier